# Split JSON file into <16MB for ingestion to Snowflake

Tags: python, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to ingest this data into Snowflake. The file is too big. The suggestion of

```
STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY = FALSE
```

...is not any use here. I've done a lot of searching. DQ seems to be a good option and I have it installed on my Windows 10 machine but cannot figure out which arguments I need to use and the documentation is beyond me at the moment.

I thought of working with the file as text in python but have not got that working either.

I have not worked with JSON much. Seems like there must be a simple solution that I am missing. All help appreciated.

**Source file:**

https://www.kaggle.com/yamaerenay/spotify-dataset-19212020-160k-tracks?select=dict_artists.json

This is a dictionary of IDs and the IDs to which they are linked (up to 20, empty if none). The descriptions are in a different file.

**Sample Data:**

```
{'0DheY5irMjBUeLybbCUEZ2': [],
 '0DlhY15l3wsrnlfGio2bjU': [],
 '0DmRESX2JknGPQyO15yxg7': [],
 '0DmhnbHjm1qw6NCYPeZNgJ': [],
 '0Dn11fWM7vHQ3rinvWEl4E': [],
 '0DotfDlYMGqkbzfBhcA5r6': [],
 '0DqP3bOCiC48L8SM9gK4W8': [],
 '0Drs3maQb99iRglyTuxizI': [],
 '0DsPeAi1gxPPnYjgpiEGSR': [],
 '0DtvnTxgZ9K5YaPS5jdlQW': [],
 '0Du4t8UK1lBD8TnOIa3c17': [],
 '0DuJ5k2ERoAizEdgUzJGTc': [],
 '0DujX6vG6qOz2wVBCQg5Vi': [],
 '0DvBSYDq5ikdlKgp94Yamq': [],
 '0DvvojCMIqsOT1Btiwvq1h': ['3Y9UedETQztUmRuB2pYaGR',
  '6ng2L9Pwj7NeXm0vJW8LLr',
  '0QAlsftQZIVyNXDtK7PEt2',
  '32qUUy6h1wKd5jN4vRSF20',
  '7kc7HZFnOwUWd8dL8jypPf',
  '07L8VAxYnAlJwnNEWdTIHI',
  '3A6TC7BhsBm8LktswCdm0X',
  '5FeE1flsA6Vuzi4uCMtpEC',
  '7oJlnzQBZE2SAS1JrQHI3F',
  '4LVKk2qM6bwMYHT3fg5sCN',
  '5wbq8xuXzD2EONQZDhZVoQ',
  '7ofTH0nFjkbKuRTpazOzzV',
  '7e9esbJQ7IVwkxpqjSEFL9',
  '4xirLzVl1nnPPBgUFvFbFh',
  '5N6NpGkfs4tFA4HLjNA7xh',
  '2qxp4iVVSlrFAImfZmPmsP',
  '4hyy9Yw1ZxHW2WndWc92h8',
  '3fF0uc3b2sQ5Gc3R09oWej',
  '2VXQKnUs5dpfG6j7AtrH0b',
  '7vHKCt7yOiBg1Hci7izDLh'],
 '0DxcE03jyjg3wQVHUQKx8C': [],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a hard json to ingest into different rows, but we can do a quick transformation with jq:

```
jq --compact-output '. | to_entries| .[]'
```

It will transform an input like yours:

[image]

Into one easy to ingest by Snowflake:

[image]

https://jqplay.org/s/EHzqi55IK2

Comment: Thanks for this, I have got it to create a new file using this line: 

`jq --compact-output '. | to_entries| .[]' dict_artists.json > dict_artists2.json`

However, the COPY INTO statement fails with the error:

`ProgrammingError: 100069 (22P02): Error parsing JSON: invalid first byte in UTF-8 sequence: 0xff
  File 'tables/31512178577474/dict_artists2.json.gz', line 1, character 1`

If I try to view the JSON file using this code:

`with open(csv) as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)`

...I get this error:

`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Can you try without .gz?

Comment: I tried that and this is the error now: `ProgrammingError: 100069 (22P02): Error parsing JSON: invalid first byte in UTF-8 sequence: 0xff
  File 'tables/31512178581562/dict_artists2.json', line 1, character 1
  Row 0, column JSON_DATA`

Comment: Can you upload the json file to somewhere where we can check what's going on with it?

Comment: Morning Felipe. It is available [here](https://www.kaggle.com/yamaerenay/spotify-dataset-19212020-160k-tracks?select=dict_artists.json)

Comment: I know that's where the original lives. But what about the one you transformed and is giving you the error?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood you. It's [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ItLvfFgs1vJzmFipaVPgDa8qcWhbnuaU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your file starts with 2 weird characters. Who added those 2 characters and how? Remove them and things will work https://i.imgur.com/RK1d2Jr.png

Answer (score 0):

Felipe gave me most of the answer, i.e. run this line in JQ:

`jq --compact-output '. | to_entries| .[]' dict_artists.json > dict_artists2.json`

Something was up with the formatting in the output of this file; Felipe's screenshot showed unexpected characters while I have since noticed in a text editor that the file was encoded as something other than just UTF8 (a slightly different flavour). I saved as UTF8 with a different file name and have successfully ingested the file.